# Screen not locked after resume from suspend (well, not immediatly)

Tags: linux-mint, linux-kernel, suspend, screensaver

I have a laptop with `Linux Mint` (`Cinnamon` desktop). `Screensaver` setting is to `Lock the computer when put to sleep`. However, often I see flash of my desktop (the content is displayed momentarily, like Nemo file manager today) before screen gets locked after I open the lid (in case when I closed the lid when desktop was not locked at the time). After I close-open the lid, screen is locked right from the start.

IMHO not very good thing from security perspective. I suspect it takes time for `screensaver` to act after computer wakes and sometimes the functionality to turn-on the display works faster in the `kernel`. Is this hypothesis correct?

Is there a way to fix that? Does this happen on other distros of Linux?

Comment: I've seen pretty much the behaviour with gnome shell on ubuntu 16.04 i'm curious if à fix exists

Comment: OK thats a really old question but it happen to me right now, I'm on arch linux with GDM and gnome

Comment: @eephyne, now on Linux Mint 20 I observe screen for as long as I like after I open the lid. Password prompt is not displayed, but if I enter password at that frozen screen it unlocks. I work from home now, but still it is an interesting issue.